# Order Items are missing in Admin Sales -> Order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, orders, magento2.4

I am facing very critical error, Items are not showing in admin Sales => Order section. Customers are placing an order successfully but in Admin Sales => Order items are missing. please check screenshot.

But items are available in database but not showing in Sales Order section. When i am creating invoice then items are showing in invoice.

How to i can fix this issue ? anyone can help me on this.

[image]

Comment: disable all custom module. may be any 3rd party extension affecting here

Comment: check if you have any exceptions in your exception log, and in your server apache error.log

Comment: i could not fin anything in log.

Comment: Now website in on liver server. i can't disable 3rd party modules.